# Printing values of JavaPairRDD<Double, Double> in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, rdd, decision-tree

I have taken the depicted results from a Spark decision tree model to a JavaPairRDD as below. Can someone help me to print the values of JavaPairRDD predictionAndLabel?

```
JavaPairRDD<Double, Double> predictionAndLabel =
                testData.mapToPair(new PairFunction<LabeledPoint, Double, Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Double, Double> call(LabeledPoint p) {
                        return new Tuple2(model.predict(p.features()), p.label());
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if I get your Question correctly but you could do something like

```
    predictionAndLabel.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println("model="+data._1() + " label=" + data._2());
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much and your answer is extremely helpful. Can you please explain me what is the variable 'data' and how I can initialize it.

Comment: "data ->" is java 8 lambda expression to iterate over collection. You can refer http://www.developer.com/java/start-using-java-lambda-expressions.html for more detail. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it resolves your issue :).

Comment: Thank you very much